# Is it possible to "get" quaternions without specifically postulating them?

Tags: reference-request, quaternions

I know that quaternions were first invented to handle description of 3D and 4D rotations, just as 2D rotations can be described by complex numbers. On the other hand, non-natural numbers can be "deduced" in a sense.

For example, starting with natural numbers (including 0), so that subtraction can be done for all numbers, we add negative numbers to get integers. To make division work the same way (well, except for division by 0), we introduce rational numbers. To "fill in the remainders", we enter real numbers. Finally, in order for any polynomials to have a solution, we add an imaginary unit and get complex numbers.

However, complex numbers are algebraically closed, which leads us to the fact that we can no longer obtain other numbers in the same way. But perhaps there are other branches of mathematics where quaternions "jump out of nowhere" at some point, just like the imaginary unit when solving $x^2 = -1$?

Comment: Maybe, not exactly the answer you are looking for, but if you ask the question "what are the real **finite-dimensional** associative division algebras?", you will inevitably be led to them (Frobenius theorem). If you ask the question "which are the **normed** (not necessarily finite-dimensional) real associative division algebras?", you will end up with the same short list. If you ask "what are the **finite-dimensional** real associative (not necessarily division) algebras carrying an absolute value?", again you end up with the same very short list (a result of Albert).

Comment: In other words, the quaternions inevitably show up in natural classification questions. I don't know if this counts as "jumping out of nowhere", but it does resolve a problem (like the complex numbers resolve the lack of a square root of negative numbers).

Comment: One way of obtaining the complex numbers from the real numbers is through the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction). If you apply the same method to the complex numbers, you get the quaternions. Apply it again und you get octonions etc.

Comment: Quaternions also like to pop "out of nowhere" in differential geometry for some reason. I was told a few years ago by a fellow student that there are actually several moduli spaces that have this property of carrying three distinct almost complex structures $I$, $J$, and $K$ that interact via the quaternionic relations. I don't have a good conceptual explanation as to why this should be the case and find it rather mysterious.

Comment: (This has to do the existence of Hyperkähler metric, which is very special.)

Comment: @M.G. This is very natural from the perspective of special holonomy.  Relatively few Lie groups can appear as the holonomy of a Riemannian manifold, and the unitary quaternionic matrices are one of them;  the Riemannian metrics that have this holonomy are exactly the ones with such an I,J,K and a compatible Kahler metric.

Comment: @M.G.  Maybe a higher level way of saying this is that any real irreducible representation of a Lie group which is not irreducible with complex coefficients has an action of the quaternions.  C^2, thought of as a real representation of SU(2) is the most basic example.

Comment: @BenWebster: ah, thanks, this is nice! So, in a sense it is a "statistical" phenomenon and not necessarily special to moduli spaces alone.

Comment: If you allow matrices as algebraic construction, quaternions are formed by 4x4 real matrices.

Comment: Quaternions were not invented in order to handle 4d rotations (even though that turned out to be an application).

Comment: I do not think that quaternions were invented for the purpose of handling rotations. Instead, Hamilton was looking for a 3D ring or field analogous to the complex numbers in 2D. He had an epiphany, that this might be possible in 4D and discovered the quaternions somehow. Only later were they seen to be useful for 3D and 4D rotations.

Comment: Hamilton was an early graffiti artist, he left his mark on Broom bridge. I doubt very much that he was considering 4D rotations.

Answer (score 42):

Let $S_2$ denote the set of all integers that are representable as a sum of two squares.  Then $S_2$ is closed under multiplication, because of the identity
$$(a^2 + b^2)(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) = (a\alpha - b\beta)^2 + (a\beta + b\alpha)^2,$$
which comes from the fact that the norm of a product of two complex numbers is the product of their norms.

Let $S_4$ denote the set of all integers that are representable as a sum of four squares.  Analogously, you might hope that there is an identity which proves that $S_4$ is closed under multiplication.  With some luck and/or ingenuity, you might find [Euler's four-square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity):
$$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2) = (a\alpha - b\beta - c\gamma - d\delta)^2 + (a\beta + b\alpha + c\delta - d\gamma)^2 + (a\gamma - b\delta + c\alpha + d\beta)^2 + (a\delta + b\gamma - c\beta + d\alpha)^2.$$
You might then wonder if there is a number system analogous to the complex numbers that "explains" this identity, and thereby might be led to discover the quaternions.

By the way, this is not an isolated fact, because there are deep connections between the theory of quaternion algebras and the theory of quadratic forms.

Answer (score 31):

Quaternions—in the sense of objects that obey the relations of the quaternion group—arise automatically in Lie Theory.  The most elementary noncommutative continuous group is $SO(3)$, and if you want to understand rotations in three dimension, you obviously have to understand the representations of this group—how it can act on scalar, vector, and higher tensor objects, for instance.  The most natural way to do this is to study the Lie algebra; even if you are not going to fully generalize to abstract Lie algebras, you are going to be led to a study of the generators $T_{i}$, which obey a commutation relation $[T_{i},T_{j}]=\epsilon_{ijk}T_{k}$.

However, if you explore the representations of this Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, you find that there are a whole bunch of group representations *missing*—just like there are missing roots to real polynomials!  There is one finite-dimensional irreducible representation of the algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ for dimension $n$ for each integer $n\geq1$.  Yet the group $SO(3)$ only has representations with odd dimension!  We know the reason for this now is that there is a topological obstruction; $SO(3)$ is not simply connected.  However, even without understanding the general topological issue involved, it straightforward to locate another group—the universal cover $SU(2)$ of $SO(3)$—which has the same Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)\approx\mathfrak{so}(3)$ but which does have all the representations, including a two-dimensional fundamental representation.  The generators of this two-dimensional representation (from which, via tensor products, all the representations can be built up)
$$i\sigma_1=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & i \\
i & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
i\sigma_2=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
i\sigma_3=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i
\end{array}\right]$$
then have precisely the multiplication table of the quaternions $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$.

Of course, the connection between the quaternion algebra and the theory of continuous groups goes on to be much deeper.  However, this is the first place that it is likely to be evident that the introduction of objects that obey the defining relations for quaternions is necessary.

Comment: How are you defining "most elementary"?  (On the open half-plane, the nonabelian Lie group of affine functions x ⟼ ax+b for real a, b with a > 0 seems more elementary to me.)

Answer (score 15):

The group algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ of every finite group is a direct sum of simple algebras. If you decide to compute this decomposition for some small groups, then you will discover that for the 8-element quaternion group $Q_8$, you get a direct sum of four copies of $\mathbb{R}$ and one copy of the quaternion algebra. (Over $\mathbb{C}$, you get four copies of $\mathbb{C}$ and one of the $2\times 2$ matrix algebra $M_2(\mathbb{C}))$.

Comment: This was my first thought... but this starts from the "quaternion" group, whose law basically captures the law of the quaternions.

Answer (score 9):

They can be deduced via Dirac Belt Trick, see [Understanding Quaternions and the Dirac Belt Trick](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1778) by Mark Staley. This Trick is also known as [Plate Trick.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick)

Comment: This answer is too short.  Answers should stand on their own without linked-to material.

Answer (score 2):

Given a normed vector space, with the basic operators of addition, scalar multiplication, and squared norm, you can generalize to an algebra by taking the free algebra over the vectors modulo $\mathbf u+\mathbf v=\mathbf w$, $a\mathbf v=\mathbf w$, and $a = \mathbf v^2$ for all such identities that hold in the usual sense.* The result is called the Clifford algebra of the vector space.

Within the algebra there is a subalgebra called the even algebra, which is generated by the products of even numbers of vectors.

The even Clifford algebra of $\mathbb R^3$ is isomorphic to the quaternions. If you take every nonzero vector in $\mathbb R^3$ to represent a reflection in the plane normal to itself, then the product of an even number of them is equal to a quaternion that represents that rotation in the usual way.

* There is a bit of awkwardness with the zero vector, which is equal to the zero scalar in the Clifford algebra. I'm not sure how to deal with that properly, but perhaps all that's necessary is to add the identity $0=\mathbf 0$.